# Can not enter both kernel versions: unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0)

Tags: boot, kernel, mount

Ubuntu 20.04:
I have already read several articles about this error. But I couldn't find the answer. Most of answers suggest to switch to another kernel version which works. But my problem is none of them works and show the same error:

-- [ end Kernel] panic - not syncing: VFS: Unable to mount root fs on unknown-block(0,0) ]---

I could not open the recovery mode. So I am not able to run the commands.

Last time, my computer was out of memory because of swapfile. Also, initrd.img files could be removed.

I read the article about using USB or CD. But it says that it may cause a serious damage.
I'm asking if there is an another option.

Comment: The question doesn't have any information to work with. What is the OS? It looks like your disk failed.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to mention it's Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Boot with a LiveUSB and check your disks.